# Is it right to use 1 database for both account info and content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, database-design, asp.net-mvc-5

In *most* ASP.NET Mvc tutorials, you see people creating simple models and then scaffolding controllers with views, using Entity Framework.

In most tutorials you will also see that they create a new DbContext class which will have the DbSets. I understand that this is a good thing to do for educational purpose, to help the person understand how it works.
But the account system that comes with a default Mvc project always links to **"DefaultConnection"**.

Some tutorials will also make use of the account system to advance further, but that means that at this point you would have 2 databases running to support your web app.

- one for the account info
- one for the details of your model(s)

Is this the correct way to work? or do most developers/companies just use 1 database for both of these?

My reason for asking is because i found this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) which uses both of these aspects and works on 1 database and it is the first time i see this being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no right or wrong way. You need to evaluate the requirements and time lines for your projects and decide which options suits you best.From personal experience, in all the projects I worked on, the account info and the models reside on the same database.

Remember that if you have two databases you will need to create two data contexts to access them.If the database needs to be moved to another server, you would need to move **two** databases and change the connection string in **two** places, also the maintainance and upkeep on the DB would need to be performed in two different places.It's really a maintainance headache and should be avoided in my opinion unless your requirements have some compelling reason that you should place account info into a separate DB.

Comment: Perhaps asking "right or wrong" is a wrong way to ask my question. Still your answer is clear enough for me.